# Closure of context-free languages under left-half

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties

The regular languages are [known](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71021/closure-of-regular-languages-are-closed-under-certain-cut-operations) to be closed under the operation "left half":
$$
\operatorname{left}(L) = \{ x \in \Sigma^* : xy \in L \text{ for some } y \in \Sigma^* \text{ s.t. } |x|=|y| \}
$$
What about the context-free languages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If L is context-free, must FH(L) be context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32627/if-l-is-context-free-must-fhl-be-context-free) Well, OK, took me quite some time to actually find that question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L = \{a^nb^na^mbba^{3m} : n,m \geq 1 \}$, which is clearly context-free. Then
$$
\operatorname{half}(L) \cap a^+b^+a^+b = \{ a^nb^na^nb : n \geq 1\},
$$
which is not context-free. Hence $\operatorname{half}(L)$ is not context-free.

(If $L$ is a unary context-free language then $L$ is regular, and so $\operatorname{half}(L)$ is regular.)