# Closure of context-free languages under "removal of a regular language from the right"

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I have a homework that I can't solve can somebody help me?

If $\Sigma$ is an alphabet, $R$ is regular and $L$ is context-free. Is the language $$P = \{\alpha\in\Sigma^*\mid \alpha\beta\in L\text{ for some }\beta\in R\}$$ context-free?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that a language is context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18524/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-context-free)

Comment: (or [How to prove that a language is not context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/265/9550), if it's not context-free.) What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just doing your homework for you is unlikely to really help you.

Comment: The operation is called **quotient**. Possible duplicate of [If $L$ is context-free and $R$ is regular, then $L / R$ is context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1886/if-l-is-context-free-and-r-is-regular-then-l-r-is-context-free)

Answer (score 1):

Let me prove that if $L$ is regular then so is $P$. The proof in your case is similar. Let $\Sigma' = \{ \sigma' : \sigma \in \Sigma \}$ be a copy of the alphabet $\Sigma$. Let $s$ be the $\Sigma$-substitution $s(\sigma) = \{\sigma,\sigma'\}$, let $t$ be the $\Sigma$-homomorphism $t(\sigma) = \sigma'$, and let $d$ be the $\Sigma \cup \Sigma'$-homomorphism $d(\sigma) = \sigma$, $d(\sigma') = \epsilon$. Then
$$
P = d(s(L) \cap \Sigma^* t(R)).
$$

As an aside, the class of languages obtained by dividing a context-free language by a context-free language consists of all r.e. languages. See for example [The family of one-counter languages is closed under quotient](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00267045) by     Latteux, Leguy and Ratoandromanana.