# is there a non-context free language A such that A1 is context free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

> Is there a non-context free language A over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$ such that $A1 := \{a1 : a\in A\}$ is context free?

I was thinking of the language $A = \{0^n 1^{n-1} : n > 0\}.$ Unfortunately, this language is context-free. I’m not sure if one might be able to show that context-free languages are closed under the operation of removing the last bit from every such nonempty string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $L$ is context-free and $R$ is regular, then $L / R$ is context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1886/if-l-is-context-free-and-r-is-regular-then-l-r-is-context-free)

Answer (score 1):

No. Note that $A = A1 / \{1\}$, the right quotient of $A1$ over $\{1\}$. Since $\{1\}$ is a regular language, we know that $A$ is context-free when $A1$ is context-free, thanks to [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1886/91753)  that shows the right quotient of a context-free language over a regular language is also context-free.